# How to only show the view and not the (view + links) upon clicking the links?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have written a code which upon clicking the link routes to the view. But the links don't disappear. Please guide me on how I could only let the view be shown and not the links. I am sharing images for more clarification

**App.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

import {BrowserRouter, Route, Link, Routes} from 'react-router-dom';

import Buyer from './Container/Buyer/Buyer';
import Seller from './Container/Seller/Seller';

import classes from './App.css';

class App extends Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div className={classes.App}>
          <p>Shop</p>
          <ul>

              <li><Link to='/buyer'>I want to Buy</Link></li>
              <li><Link to='/seller'>I want to Sell</Link></li>
           </ul>
          
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/buyer"  element={<Buyer/>} />
            <Route path="/seller"  element={<Seller/>} />
          </Routes>

          


        </div>
      
      </BrowserRouter>
       
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

[image]

Initially, I want only the links and "shop" to appear and upon clicking one of the links the "shop" and links should disappear and the view must only appear.

But in my case, the "Shop " and links do not disappear upon clicking also initially the view of the buyer also appears which should appear only after clicking the link "I want to buy".

Please let me know if more description is required for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the buyer to route to another view when he clicks on a link using `<Link>` then you need to specify which component to render when the path matches the current path. You may use "component" attribute.

```
<Router>
 <Route path="/buyer"  component={Buyer} />
 <Route path="/seller"  component={Seller} />
</Router>
```

Your 'import' needs to be changed to 'router'. The same to use in the jsx to wrap your routes.

```
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Link, Router} from 'react-router-dom';
```

You may use 'render' attribute to render jsx as a component through inline function. The difference between 'component' and 'render' attribute is
that component attribute remounts the component to be rendered each time the App component here is being evaluated.

You can read the official docs for more deails:

https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Route

Comment: in the new react-router-dom v6 the Route component do not take `component` so my usage of `element ` is correct